# Wordpress theme pages have disappeared after host database server change

Tags: mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

A friend of mine got in touch because his wordpress site was showing "error establishing database connection" (the website has been working for 2 years up until now). I checked out his config pinged the database IP and found it timing out. I told him many times he needs to contact his host but he never knows what i'm on about so gets frustrated and just expects me to work magic.

Anyway i visited an address i got sent by i assume the dev/previous dev which took me to phpmyadmin could log into the database, all data is still there, great.

i cannot get the ip as he wont contact the host. so i tried the IP of the phpmyadmin site, no luck (i assume its some sort of reverse proxy as i believe he has shared hosting)

so i just try the 0.0.0.0 meta-address. this works fine

i also notice the database name, user and password has been changed by someone since then. so i plug these new credentials in. Visit the website, great its back up.

however when i visit the site it makes me go through the "wordpress install" which i find weird as i assumed the website would just work. the site just shows the default wordpress page. his website is now gone. i don't use wordpress because its wordpress. so my knowlage is now very limited at this point. Iv looked at the database and i can see in the `{websitename}posts` table that all his content is there still. for example all the paragraphs for the services he provides, image links etc. i look in `wp-content/uploads/2018/01` and all the pictures the website had are still there.

When i go to the `wp-admin` UI and click on pages tab, there are no pages. all his previous ones are gone. i go to media tab and there no images i go to appearance and activate the theme that his dev used. still nothing. its as if its a fresh install.

as all his content is still i the database and all the files like images are still on the server etc. there must be a way to get his custom pages back?

i'm not sure when he last had someone touch wordpress or any code but is it safe to say the hosts making this change and whoever changed the database name and user is to blame? (he is going to want to know what went wrong)

if its any sort of help [here](https://themeforest.net/search/wolverine?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIrveE_bj-5gIVGLLtCh0ftQ6fEAAYASAAEgLrT_D_BwE) is the theme that is used

any help is much appreciated, thanks

**UPDATE**

i can see in the `{sitename}posts table` the `post_title` column has the name of his pages in `post_status` is publish or inherit `comment_status` is closed `ping_status` is closed

Comment: This all sounds a little fishy to me. "the database name, user and password has been changed by someone since then" is never something I'd want to hear. "whoever changed the database name and user is to blame" - sure they are, but who? The site/db may be compromised.  If I were you: 1) back that database the hell up. In phpmyadmin :vomit: you can export all as sql. 2) if Wordpress has gone to the install screen, it's probably because it's hooked up to the wrong db/table. Check wp-config.php database_name and database_prefix match that on phpmyadmin. 3) Find out wh changed db creds. 4) Run away

Comment: XD my first instinct was run away. i back the database up already i also made a change to the default page and i can see it got added to the table where all his content is so i assume its the correct database and table but i will check out the prefix thing anyway. in your opinion is his website/pages that were made using the theme un recoverable?

Comment: In my opinion, if the database was intact previously, and you've backed it up, I think it's recoverable. Have a look in the db table called wp_posts (or [sitename]_posts) and look at the column called post_content. In there you should see content for all the old posts/pages... I hope. Fingers crossed!

Comment: I checked the prefix thing and you were right. i just had to change the prefix and the site came back up. and OMG were you right about running!! whoever is hosting their website use phpmyadmin over http!!!!!!!!!!!! we need some sort of authority we can report these criminals too XD also the website is terrible ;)

Comment: Well at least the data is there. Now run :D

Comment: Thanks for the help appreciate it *runs to another continent*